# How to update a URL in a python file for Selenium testing

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am needing to find a way to update my URL in my python file used for python testing. Every time a new build is released the URL increments, i.e. build1.test.com, build2.test.com.

Is there a way to automatically update this URL to increment up when the new build is released?

```
import unittest
from page import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://build10.test.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by having your test methods read the build information from an external file.  I have test information in json files which are read and are passed into each test when they are run.

```
import json

with open('../test data/testdata.json) as data_file
    json_contents = json.load(data_file)
```

and your json file could be something like this:

```
{
    "Latest Build": "build10"
}
```

You read in this information and use that to construct your URL for the test.

```
build_number = json_contents["Latest Build"]
build_url = "https://%s.test.com" % build_number
self.driver.get(build_url)
```

You could possibly write a script to update this file with the latest build info, but that would depend on what you have access to.

Comment: This seems like a great solution, I'll get back to you once I get it set up!